# Переписать с if на case (D)

Tags: d, if

Код не совсем на Ди. Хочу спросить, можно ли как-то следующий код оформить через блок switch. Мне кажется, это сделало бы код красивее. Или подскажите любой другой вариант, как тоже самое можно было бы записать:

```
    if( (command == 1) && openFile(&file, "r") ) {
        readFile(file, &dataArray, selectSpecifier());      // считали данные из файла

        if( ! checkData(&dataArray) ) {         // проверяем файл
            writeln("Erroneous file content! "); 
        }
```

Если что, можете показать пример на C# или С++, я попробую переписать ваше решение на Ди.

Comment: Во-первых, если код написан на D, то так и напишите, не морочьте людям голову - в заголовке у вас C#, в метках C# и С++, а код, оказывается, на D, что само по себе вводит в заблуждение. 

Во-вторых, похожесть языков не означает полной идентичности - скажем, в том же C# switch по строкам возможен, а в С++ - нет (в D могут быть какие-то другие нюансы)

В-третьих, не знаю конечно насчет D? но в C# вы этот код вы на switch никак не перепишете (во всяком случае адекватным способом). Подозреваю, что и в других Языках тоже

В-четвертых, с точки зрения ветвлений код вполне нормален, не заморачивайтес

Comment: Шарп - это целиком и полностью ОО-язык, тут же ФП, передача по ссылке, передача дескриптора файла, у меня почему-то есть ощущение, что это все-таки ветка просто С, а не C#.

Comment: Исправил описание, чтобы не вводить людей в заблуждение.

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(1){
    import std.file;
    case 1:
        auto data = read("файл.txt");
        break;
    default:
        assert(0); // что-то пошло не так 1 != 1
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в ваш ответ дельное описание решения проблемы или кода, чтобы пользователи могли быстрее понять ваш ответ.